# jQuery anchor tag text re-write project

Tags: jquery, regex, wordpress

I have a wordpress site that im list out files in a directory. The code gets spit out as

```
<a href="http://helpdesk-3/acme/wp-content/uploads/important_documents/compliance_documents/sample_document.pdf">sample_document.pdf</a>
```

Im trying to wrap my head around using jQuery to re-write the link display text to camel case, no extension, and spaces. So it would run and re-write it as

```
<a href="http://helpdesk-3/acme/wp-content/uploads/important_documents/compliance_documents/sample_document.pdf">Sample Document</a>
```

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Your html in both examples look to be the same?

Comment: search every link in page...or are these in a certain container?

Comment: @DavidThomas the text within the `a` is different.

Comment: @DavidThomas I think OP is referring to the content of the anchor rather than the href, as that is the only thing that differs between the two examples - even though the title states differently.

Comment: I could wrap all the links in a single container div it would be easier.

Comment: @JamesMontagne: ah, I was mis-led by the `href` part of the question title. Silly me... =/ Also: that's not camelCase...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('a').each(function() { // Loop over all links
    var txt = $(this).text().split('.'); // Link contents, split on '.'
    txt.pop(); // remove last (the extension)
    txt = txt.join('.').replace(/_/g, ' '); // replace '_' with spaces
    txt = $.map(txt.split(' '), function(v) { // split on spaces
        // and uppercase the 1st letter
        return v.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + v.substring(1, v.length);
    }).join(' ');
    $(this).text(txt); // set the new text
});​
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/f6x9P/1/

Comment: Deleted my answer, upvoting this instead.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks for the comments in the code, helps me learn it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using Wordpress, it would probably be easier to just use PHP.

```
<?php
    $doc = 'sample_document.pdf';
    $array = explode('.', $doc);
    $string = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $array[0]));
    echo $string;
```

Comment: `$array[0]` wouldn't work if the file had multiple `.`s in it.  Like `sample_document_2.0.pdf`.

Comment: Then we edit it to remove the extension and reform the array, replacing the spaces. `<?php
 $doc = sample_document.pdf;
 $array = explode('.', $str);
 $noExt = array_pop($array);
 $string = ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', implode('.', $noExt)));
 echo $string;
?>`

Answer (score 0):

```
//setup function to capitalize each word in a string, breaking the string at the underscore characters
function capitalize (str) {

        //get each word
        var split = str.split('_');

        //loop through the words
        for (var i = 0, len = split.length; i < len; i++) {

            //set the first letter to uppercase, and the rest to lowercase
            split[i] = split[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + split[i].slice(1).toLowerCase();
        }

        //now return the new string, words separated by spaces
        return split.join(' ');
}

//select the elements you want to update, then update their text
$('a').text(function (index, oldText) {
    return capitalize(oldText);
});
```

This will take care of spaces.

When you pass `.text()` a function, you are asking to loop over the elements selected, and update their text. Whatever you `return` will be the new text, and the anonymous function is passed the index of the current element in the selection and the current element's value: http://api.jquery.com/text

Answer (score 0):

Very likely need to create a far better selector than looping every a tag in page

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var txtArr = $this.text().split('.')[0].split('_');
    for (i = 0; i < txtArr.length; i++) {
        txtArr[i] = txtArr[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txtArr[i].slice(1);
    }
    $this.text(txtArr.join(' '));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure. But strainght javascript is used for string manipulation. You want to get the text value of the anchor:

`atext = $('a').text();`

Then apparently you want to strip off the pdf extension. I'll assume there is only one period in the filename, and extension could be anything:

`atext = atext.split('.');`

atext[0] now contains everything to left of period. Assume that underscore is the seperator:

`atext = atext[0].split('_');`
`camel = ''`

```
for word in atext {
  w = word.substring(0,1).toUppercase();
  w = w + word.substring(1);
  camel = camel + w + ' ';
}
```

finally change the text in the tag:

`$('a').text(camel);`

There are things you'll need to improve here. Using jQuery to get 'a' will return all anchors; so change the match string to be more specific. Or, if you do want to change all anchor tags, then you need to put all the string manipulation code in a function and apply it to all the matched anchor tags.